# Only selected checkbox should perform further ajax query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 7 checkbox, of which i want values of only selected checkbox to make further ajax query to insert data in database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH58E.png)

Javascript must initialize the value of selected checkbox and pass them forward to the php file were insertion is going to be made. As I am new to ajax, I am unable to understand were am I making mistake. Here is the code that I currently have.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#askquestion").click(function(){

var alll = $('#alll').val();
var bff = $('#bff').val();
var relative = $('#relative').val();
var coligues = $('#coligues').val();
var acquintance = $('#acquintance').val();
var friends = $('#friends').val();
var follower = $('#follower').val();
var qid = $('#qid').val();


 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajaxaskquestion.php",
          data : {
              alll:alll,
              bff:bff,
              relative:relative,
              coligues:coligues,
              acquintance:acquintance,
              friends:friends,
              follower:follower,
              qid:qid
              },success: function(data){
                    alert("done");
                },
      error: function (data){
          ("not done");
      }
 });
 });
 });
```

```
session_start();
require_once("connect.php");

 $alll = $_POST["alll"];
 $bff = $_POST["bff"];
 $friends = $_POST["friends"];
 $coligues = $_POST["coligues"];
 $relative = $_POST["relative"];
 $acquintance = $_POST["acquintance"];
 $follower = $_POST["follower"];
 $qid=$_POST["qid"];

if(isset($_POST)){

   if(isset($alll)){
// perform some function
}

else{
      if(isset($bff)){
        // perform some function

}
      if(isset($friends)){
        // perform some function

}
//and so on..
}
}
 else{
 echo "Question not sent";
 }
```

I know the method which I used is very long and far away from being subtle. Any and every suggestion is welcomed. Thank you

Comment: Use codeigniter framework with angularjs thats good for your issue

Comment: Yes, you should most definitely add two humongous frameworks to make a checkbox work, it's the only viable solution here.

Comment: @HenriqueYahCenteno but don't forget to install typo3 and wordpress as well!

Answer (score 0):

what about using jquery's own `:checked` selector?

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajaxaskquestion.php",
          data : {
              alll: $("#alll").is(":checked"),
              bff:$("#bff").is(":checked"),

              /* ... and so on */
              },
          success: function(data){
              alert("done");
          },
          error: function (data){
              ("not done");
          }  
 });
```

then in your PHP file:

```
if($_POST["all"])
{
    // do stuff
}
/* and so on */
```

Comment: did you mean if(isset($_POST["all"]))

Comment: it is not working in both the case. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I tested it on chrome and its working fine but in mozilla nothing happens when i click submit. Any suggestions on that ?